# Can TimeDuration type be an instance of Semigroup and Monoid?

Tags: haskell

In an attempt to find a quick and easy way to add different time periods, it occurred to me that I could declare them instances of Semigroup and Monoid. Are the following instantiations valid?

```
data TimeDuration = S Int | M Int | H Int deriving (Show, Eq)

instance Semigroup TimeDuration where
    S n1 <> S n2 = S (n1 + n2)
    M n1 <> M n2 = S (60 * (n1 + n2))
    H n1 <> H n2 = S (3600 * (n1 + n2))
    S n1 <> M n2 = S (n1 + 60 * n2)
    S n1 <> H n2 = S (n1 + 3600 * n2)
    M n1 <> S n2 = S (60 * n1 + n2)
    M n1 <> H n2 = S (60 * n1 + 3600 * n2)
    H n1 <> S n2 = S (3600 * n1 + n2)
    H n1 <> M n2 = S (3600 * n1 + 60 * n2)

instance Monoid TimeDuration where
    mempty = S 0
```

Example:  mconcat [S 1, M 2, M 3, S 2, H 1] == S 3903

User *leftaroundabout* ask me to produce more significative example. So this is a new implementation and some examples that I hope will show better the possible variety of the results of the operation (<>)

```
instance Semigroup TimeDuration where
    S n1 <> S n2 = S (n1 + n2)
    M n1 <> M n2 = M (n1 + n2)
    H n1 <> H n2 = H (n1 + n2)
    S n1 <> M n2 = S (n1 + 60 * n2)
    M n1 <> S n2 = S n2 <> M n1
    S n1 <> H n2 = S (n1 + 3600 * n2)
    H n1 <> S n2 = S n2 <> H n1
    M n1 <> H n2 = M (n1 + 60 * n2)
    H n1 <> M n2 = M n1 <> H n1 


instance Monoid TimeDuration where
    mempty = S 0
    mconcat [] = S 0
    mconcat xs = foldr1 (\y acc -> y <> acc) xs

-- ex. mconcat [M 2, M 3] == M 5
-- ex. mconcat [H 2, H 3] == H 5
-- ex. mconcat [M 2, M 3, S 1] == S 301
-- ex. mconcat [H 2, H 3, M 1] == M 301
-- ex. mconcat [H 2, H 3, S 1] == S 18001
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, that's fine. It's basically equivalent to

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric, DeriveAnyClass #-}

import Data.AdditiveGroup
import GHC.Generics

newtype TimeDuration = TimeDuration {getDurationInSeconds :: Integer}
  deriving (Generic, AdditiveGroup)
```

...with extra constructors for the special cases `TimeDuration 60`, `TimeDuration 180`... `TimeDuration 3600` etc. (which in your construction are actually redundant; you could better make simple builder-functions to do the same job).

The [`AdditiveGroup` typeclass](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space-0.13/docs/Data-AdditiveGroup.html) is a specialised monoid typeclass, that avoids any confusion that it might be a *multiplication monoid* instead – which wouldn't actually make any sense because dimension-wise, *time* × *time* doesn't match *time*, but for dimensionless number types like `Int` or `Double` the multiplication monoid is just as sensible as the addition one.

Because these still have an unambiguous `AdditiveGroup` instance, the `AdditiveGroup TimeDuration` instance can just be derived. It could also be written by hand

```
instance AdditiveGroup TimeDuration where
  zeroV = TimeDuration 0
  TimeDuration δt₀ ^+^ TimeDuration δt₁ = TimeDuration $ δt₀ + δt₁
```

One particularly nice thing about `AdditiveGroup`: it's a precursor to [`VectorSpace`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space-0.13/docs/Data-VectorSpace.html) which gives you a multiplication that *does* make sense, namely

```
instance VectorSpace TimeDuration where
  type Scalar TimeDuration = Integer
  factor *^ TimeDuration δt = TimeDuration $ factor * δt
```

Comment: The real goal of my post was to verify the possibility of using Semigroup and Monoid with complex ADTs. TimeDuration is just an example. Anyway, thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: If it's actually for _complex_ ADTs (not sure what that's supposed to mean), then your question was perhaps not very much to the point. You may want to ask a new one that depicts the use case more accurately. At least for physical-quantity types, it's generally best to keep the implementation simple to one conventional unit, and expose only conversion-safe combinators / constructors.

Comment: For the moment, I do not have very clear ideas. When I have formulated some more significant examples, I will publish them. Thanks anyway for your answer.

Comment: An example that implies a complex ADT is that of a set of personal profiles related to a single person but coming from different and more or less complete information sources. The operation (<>) would indicate the "merging" of two profiles.

Comment: That sounds like it would be isomorphic to `Data.Map` (which is already a monad).

Answer (score 2):

If we are writing an instance for a class with laws, the first sanity check should, in general, be whether the instance follows them. For `Semigroup`, there is the associativity law...

```
(x <> y) <> z = x <> (y <> z)
```

... while `Monoid` adds the identity laws:

```
mempty <> x = x
x <> mempty = x
```

Your instance follows the laws as long as only `S` values are involved (as it boils down to adding seconds). However, the identity laws are broken once the other constructors are brought into play, as in:

```
mempty <> H 2 = S 7200
```

We might be tempted to argue that `H 2` and `S 7200` are morally the same, and the difference between them is merely a presentation issue (cf. how `show . read` is, strictly speaking, not `id` as it normalises formatting). The question, then, would become why are `H` and `M` necessary if they aren't meant to be used for any relevant distinctions (cf. the other answers).

Comment: The difference consists in the intentions of H (hours) and S (seconds) and in the easiness of human understanding of the two quantities. As a 20! is different from 2432902008176640000, intensionally and cognitively speaking. Thanks anyway for the articulated answer.

Answer (score 1):

This looks ok but why not just do this?

```
newtype TimeDuration = Seconds (Sum Integer) deriving (Show, Eq, Monoid, Semigroup)
```

I think you need extensions to derive semigroup and monoid through the newtype, and you need to import `Sum` from `Data.Foldable`

You can have functions for the rest:

```
seconds = Seconds
minutes = seconds . (*60)
hours = minutes . (*60)
```

Another thing you might want would be:

```
data TimDuration = Duration { seconds :: Int, minutes :: Int, hours :: Integer }
```

And define a function to normalise this. But here’s a question to demonstrate that actually adding durations and times is difficult: is adding a minute the same as adding 60s? One would think so but what if say the time is 23:59:00 and the last minute has a leap second? In such a case if you add 60 seconds you get to 23:59:60. If you add a minute should you get 23:59:60 or 00:00:00 for the next day? In this case I think saying a minute is 60s is sensible. But how long is a day or a month? What happens if you add a day to 12:00 the day before the clocks change. Should you get 12:00 the next day or 13:00/11:00? And if you add a month to 29 January should you get 28 February or 1 March? And what about on leap years? Time is hard once things aren’t always seconds.

Comment: The real goal of my post was to verify the possibility of using Semigroup and Monoid with complex ADTs. TimeDuration is just an example. Anyway, thanks for the suggestions.